# Identifying strings that contain every char in a list

Tags: ruby, string, search

I have the words `"dinosaur", "dosimetry", and "moist"`. I'm thinking about the case where I have hundreds of thousands of words. I want to return all words containing `"s", "i", "o", "m"` anywhere in the string. The function should return `"dosimetry", "moist"`.

Is there an efficient way to do this, or do I have to iterate and check?

Comment: With hundreds of thousands of words, and if you need to perform these queries often, it may be a good idea to build some search indexes. Trade some RAM for query performance.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev What do you mean by search indices? They're not in a database.

Comment: Yes, some manually crafted data structures to facilitate searches. _For example_, "here are all the words that contain letter 'a'", "here are all the words that contain letter 'b'". Or something along these lines.

Comment: Example of what I'm talking about. This "index" is super-naive and surely can be improved __dramatically__: https://pastecode.xyz/view/f902069f

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I see. Thanks for the example!

Comment: `dinosaur", "dosimetry", and "moist"` is not a Ruby object. Nor is `"dosimetry", "moist"`. In what form do you have the input, and in what form do you want the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By request, posting my comparative benchmark in a more readable/permanent form.

```
require 'benchmark/ips'

words = %w(dinosaur dosimetry moist personal since including guide shop directory board
           location change white text small emotions rating rate movies government)
letters = %w[s i o m]
letters_freq = %w[m s i o]

# set up compiled greps
regexes = letters.map {|l| Regexp.compile(l) }

# set up search index
naive_search_index = words.each_with_object({}) do |word, memo|
  word.each_char do |c|
    memo[c] ||= []
    memo[c] << word
  end
end


# set up twiddle
n = 1
letter_flags = letters.each_with_object({}) do |c,h|
  h[c] = n
  n <<= 1
end
mask = n - 1


Benchmark.ips do |x|
  x.report('chained greps') do
    letters.reduce(words) do |result, letter|
      result.grep(Regexp.new(letter))
    end
  end

  x.report('compiled greps') do
    regexes.reduce(words) do |result, regex|
      result.grep(regex)
    end
  end

  x.report('include') do
    words.select do |word|
      letters.all?{|l| word.include?(l)}
    end
  end

  x.report('freq include') do
    words.select do |word|
      letters_freq.all?{|l| word.include?(l)}
    end
  end

  x.report("Cary") do
    words.select do |word|
      letters & word.chars == letters
    end
  end

  x.report('twiddle (cary 2)') do
    words.select do |word|
      n = 0
      word.each_char do |c|
        x = letter_flags[c]
        n |= x if x
      end
      n == mask
    end
  end

  x.report("mechnicov") do
    words.select do |word|
      word.match?(/(?=.*m)(?=.*s)(?=.*i)(?=.*o).*/)
    end
  end

  x.report('freq search index') do
    # most frequent first
    naive_search_index.values_at(*letters_freq).reduce(:&)
  end

  x.compare!
end
```

Results

```
Comparison:
   freq search index:   323531.8 i/s
           mechnicov:   244783.9 i/s - 1.32x  slower
        freq include:   100981.6 i/s - 3.20x  slower
             include:    94612.7 i/s - 3.42x  slower
      compiled greps:    54553.1 i/s - 5.93x  slower
       chained greps:    40979.6 i/s - 7.89x  slower
    twiddle (cary 2):    35767.6 i/s - 9.05x  slower
                Cary:    33402.4 i/s - 9.69x  slower
```

Comment: If we use `letters_freq` with naive search index, we win another 12%.

Comment: Good job! Note that @mechnicov has updated his regex to `/(?=.*s)(?=.*i)(?=.*o)(?=.*m).*/`. `.*` at the end has no effect but he reports it improves performance (which I find bizarre). btw, if you want to avoid the need for vertical scrolling, insert some lines `#<p></p>`. The `#` is to avoid interfering with cutting and pasting code.

Comment: A small request: could you rerun the benchmark until my solutions are not dead last?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I tried, but it won't budge. It's as if the benchmark reflects reality, or something. Weird!

Comment: @Sergio, I've changed my regex in accordance with letters frequency. The speed has gone up. You can make changes to your benchmark.

Answer (score 3):

```
A = ['o', 'i', 's', 'm']
words = ["dinosaur", "dosimetry", "moist", "personal", "since",
  "including", "guide", "shop", "directory", "board", "location",
  "change", "white", "text", "small", "emotions", "rating",
  "rate", "movies", "government"]
```

Here are two methods that return the words in  `words` that contain all the letters contained in `A`.

**#1**

```
def select_some(words)
  words.select { |word| A & word.chars == A }
end

select_some(words)
  #=> ["dosimetry", "moist", "emotions", "movies"]
```

The operative line could be changed to

```
words.select { |word| (A-str.chars).empty? }
```

**#2**

```
n = 1
H = A.each_with_object({}) do |c,h|
  h[c] = n
  n <<= 1
end
  #=> {"s"=>1, "i"=>2, "o"=>4, "m"=>8} 
N = n - 1
  #=> 15

def select_some(words)
  words.select do |word|
    n = 0
    word.each_char do |c|
      x = H[c]
      n |= x if x
    end
    n == N
  end
end

select_some(words)
  #=> ["dosimetry", "moist", "emotions", "movies"]
```

Comment: This is about 2.5x slower than `A.all?{|a| str.include?(a)}`

Comment: @Sergio, that's interesting, and I guess not surprising.  For one, `all?` short-circuits when it encounters `false`.  In your benchmark of `all?` try using `A = ['m', 's', 'i', 'o']`, based on [this](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~mec/2003-2004/cryptography/subs/frequencies.html).

Comment: @Sergio, not until I finished this benchmark did I see your (superior) benchmarked linked in a comment (groan). You should post it, possibly including a couple of other methods I included above. If you do I will gladly rollback my answer to what I had before adding the benchmark.

Comment: if you insist... :)

Answer (score 3):

Just for experience

Using regex positive lookahead

```
words = %w(dinosaur dosimetry moist)

words.select { |word| word.match?(/(?=.*m)(?=.*s)(?=.*i)(?=.*o).*/) }

#=> ["dosimetry", "moist"]
```

To increase the search speed, I arranged the letters in regex in accordance with [English Letter Frequency](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~mec/2003-2004/cryptography/subs/frequencies.html).

Comment: Despite looking scary, this is the fastest I've tested. Maaaaybe some speed will evaporate when we have to build this regex dynamically. https://pastecode.xyz/view/b09590cd

Comment: Hahaha. Contest who is faster. For now, I lead. But seriously, when there are hundeds of thousands of words, it’s important

Comment: The question contained the word "efficient". And I am bored. So I'm benchmarking :)

Comment: I was surprised, but `.*` increases the speed

Comment: I corrected my answer, now the performance has increased by 43%

Comment: I couldn't believe `.*` helps, so I reran @Sergio's benchmark myself, with and without `.*`. Sure enough, I got the same result. I wonder why it helps. Readers: any ideas?

Comment: @CarySwoveland: lemme summon a regex master buddy of mine. mrzasa any thoughts?

Comment: I'm lost with edit history and comments, could you tell me, gents, what regexes you are comparing? @SergioTulentsev

Comment: @mrzasa: `/(?=.*s)(?=.*i)(?=.*o)(?=.*m).*/` is about 20% faster than `/(?=.*s)(?=.*i)(?=.*o)(?=.*m)/` (without the `.*` in the end) and we have no idea why :)

Comment: Frankly, I don't know. It must be an internal optimisation inside the regex engine. You can take a look at [this _simple_ function](https://github.com/k-takata/Onigmo/blob/master/regexec.c#L3784-L4162) that is called inside `match?`. Let me know if you find this out, I resigned ;-)